# Binary Search Implementation

Tags: java, class, abstract-class, binary-search, implementation

I want to implement a Binary Search and I have three methods for that. I want to output the amount of recursive calls needed for a specific factor.

> A factor of two means that the search space is split into half-half in each recursion step. * A factor of three means that the search space is split into one third and two thirds in each recursion step. * In each case integer division is assumed, which means fractions are rounded down.

I don't know how to call a specific element of the list haystack. How should I implement the three methods of the class BinarySearch correctly and how should I implement the main class for the input of a number and the amount of recursive calls?

Here is the class BinarySearch:

```
package u8a1;

import java.util.List;

public class BinarySearch<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> implements IBinarySearch<Key, Value>, IMeasure {

    public Key key;

    public Value value;

    public BinarySearch() {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public Value find(List<Unit<Key, Value>> haystack, Key needle)
    {
        //return haystack.isEmpty() ? null : haystack.get(0).value;
        int m, li, re;
        li = 0;
        re = haystack.size();
        //if ()
        return value;
    }
    /** 
 * Set the factor for the binary search.
 * 
 * A factor of two means that the search space is split into half-half in each recursion step.
 * A factor of three means that the search space is split into one third and two thirds in each recursion step.
 * In each case integer division is assumed, which means fractions are rounded down.
 * 
 * This method is called first after instantiation.
 * 
 * @param factor
 *            an integer value
 */
    public void setFactor(int factor)
    {
        //int m, li, re;
        //li = 0; re = haystack.size();
        //getNumberofCalls()
        return;
    }
    public int getNumberofCalls()
    {
        return 1/* + getNumberofCalls()*/;
    }
}
```

Here is the main class:

```
package u8a1;

/**
 * Main class of the Java program. 
 * 
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

//...
class Scan{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = in.nextInt();
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // we print a heading and make it bigger using HTML formatting
        System.out.println("<h4>-- Binaere Suche --</h4>");
        int anzahl = 0;
        //zahl.Scan();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = in.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Tell me if you need both Interfaces and the class Unit, but in the class BinarySearch I have the same constructor.

Comment: This looks a lot like a school exercise to me ...

Comment: And why does it look like this?

Comment: The most helpful thing right now would be how to call an element of the haystack. Then I can start to implement correctly at least one or two methods.

Comment: Several things are not clear.  What is the meaning of `factor`?  To find a needle in a haystack, you first need a List<Unit> - are you going to create this list and add Units to it? (it will need to be sorted as well).  What is the meaning of the int that the user enters in `main()`? (is this the key)?

Comment: /** 
  * Set the factor for the binary search.
  * 
  * A factor of two means that the search space is split into half-half in each recursion step.
  * A factor of three means that the search space is split into one third and two thirds in each recursion step.
  * In each case integer division is assumed, which means fractions are rounded down.
  * 
  * This method is called first after instantiation.
  * 
  * @param factor
  *            an integer value
  */

Comment: This is the comment for the method factor

Comment: In main, you will have to create an instance of `BinarySearch binarySearch`.  Then you will need to invoke `binarySearch.setFactor(x)`.  Then you will need to create a `List<Unit> haystack`, and invoke `binarySearch.find(haystack, needle)`.  Obviously you still need to complete the find method using the factor.  For the number of iterations, you can use a static variable counter which gets incremented each time the `find` method is invoked (recursively).

Comment: Your method `setFactor(int factor)` should simply set a class variable `this.factor = factor`.  It should not return anything (the method is void).  This variable factor will be used in `find` (something like `re = haystack.size() / factor`

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments. Your code is unreadable in comments. Also, not all comments are shown initially. Make it easy to help you by putting everything in one place.

Comment: There's no such thing as calling an element from the haystack. Haystack is a List, and you can get list elements. Try to get these technical terms right to avoid misunderstandings. To actually `get` an element, see the [Javadoc for List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
package u8a1;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BinarySearch<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> implements IBinarySearch<Key, Value>, IMeasure {

    private int dividedBy = 2;

    private int numOfCall = 1;

    public Key key;

    public Value value;

    public BinarySearch() {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public Value find(List<Unit<Key, Value>> haystack, Key needle)
    {
        if (haystack.size() == 0) return null;
        if (needle.compareTo(haystack.get(haystack.size()/dividedBy).key) == 0) return haystack.get(haystack.size()/dividedBy).value;
        if (haystack.size() == 1) return null;
        else if(needle.compareTo(haystack.get(haystack.size()/dividedBy).key) > 0)
        {
            ++numOfCall;
            return find(haystack.subList((haystack.size()/dividedBy), haystack.size()), needle);
        }
        else if(needle.compareTo(haystack.get(haystack.size()/dividedBy).key) < 0)
        {
            ++numOfCall;
            return find(haystack.subList(0, (haystack.size()/dividedBy)), needle);
        }
        else return null;
    }
    public void setFactor(int factor)
    {
        dividedBy = factor;
    }
    public int getNumberofCalls()
    {
        return numOfCall;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we have one search operation that is supposed to generate two outputs 1. `value` found 2. `count`.

I think two approaches can be tried :-

1. `BinarySearch` can have instance variables for  factor, list or haystack, key and count. To do a search first create an instance of `BinarySearch` with constructor that takes `list` and `key`.
   Call `setFactor()` to set factor. Call `doSearch()` or `find` with no arguments that runs on `list`, `key` instance variables and return value. While running `doSearch()` increment `count` instance variable for each recursive call. once `doSearch()` returns a `value` , call `getCount()` to get the number of recursive calls.
   With this, for each search to be done new instance of `BinarySearch` should be created.
2. Instead of returning `value` from `find` , return `response` object that contains  `count` and `value` if found or null . While starting search create the response object with count 0 and object null. Pass response object with every recursive call. At start of each recursive call increment count and return the response object once when value is found. `getNumberOfCalls()` should be defined in the `response` and be called once `find` returns the `response`.

Answer (score 0):

I got told that if I want to access the central element of the haystack, I need to write the following line:

```
Unit<Key, Value> mid_unit = haystack.get(middle);
```

Now the thing is to get it compared with needle which has the type Key. Because when this works, I just need to compare the searched element with the central element of the haystack, then if the searched element is smaller than mid_unit, I set the right limit to

```
right = middle;
```

where

```
middle = (left + right) / 2;
```

and then

```
else left = middle;
```